# Is Constant Variable defaulting to Internal Linkage Language Specific or Compiler Specific feature?

Tags: c++

I am reading from Bruce Eckel- Introduction to C++. in which it is said that in C++, generally constant variable are not allocated storage instead their values are kept in symbol table unless EXTERN is not used with const or their address is not taken.

So we can say in C++ , Const always default to Internal Linkage. but still does this feature depend on how Compiler is made for C++ language. or this will always be true ?

Comment: What you are talking about is not constant folding (which is a compiler optimization). What you are describing here is the default linkage/storage duration of `const` qualified objects, which is described by the C++ standard.

Comment: sorry i need to edit my question !! i totally left that part in my mind sir ! thanks !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`const` globals default to internal linkage. This is specified by the standard.

`const` globals *must* have storage allocated if you take their address. This is also specified by the standard.

Just because they sometimes get storage doesn't mean the compiler always has to use them that way, though. It can still substitute them in where it wants and then constant-fold expressions away.

Comment: Thanks for answer. i thought it'd be Compiler Specific. Why didn't C do  this ? i mean this can improve efficiency there too ! isn't it ?

Comment: C's `const` is much weaker than C++'s. It doesn't create true constants (you can't use `const int` variables as array bounds, for example), and doesn't affect the linkage. The only thing C `const` does is make an lvalue not be modifiable.

Comment: yes exactly. but in C++ that helps to take care for built in type !